# Ubuntu 14.04 KDE reversed green and red on images

Tags: firefox, kde

I haven't used KDE last few weeks and so I have done some regular firefox and ubuntu updates during this time. But today, I logged in with plasma desktop on my Ubuntu machine and surprisingly realised the photos on my online account are with reversed green and red colour. Firstly I thought my profile might have been hacked and the images changed though in a strange manner, but when logged out from KDE and switched back to Unity everything was looking just fine. What may cause that kind of colour inversion in KDE (currently tested only on firefox and am not sure if the issue exists in other programs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems indeed to be Firefox related problem, but in KDE only. I had to change the *`gfx.color_management.mode`* in *about:config*  Firefox section to 0 (it defaults to 2). It solved the colour issue although it might not have solved the source of the problem.